# Create column with data and float data types

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I work with a dataframe named `emails_visits`:
pandas is imported

```
    Rep  Doctor       Date   type
0     1       1 2021-01-25  email
1     1       1 2021-05-29  email
2     1       2 2021-03-15  email
3     1       2 2021-04-02  email
4     1       2 2021-04-29  email
30    1       2 2021-06-01  visit
5     1       3 2021-01-01  email
```

I want to create column "date_after" based on value in column type if it is equal to "visits" I would like to see date from column "date" otherwise empty.

I use this code:

```py
emails_visits["date_after"]=np.where(emails_visits["type"]=="visit",emails_visits["Date"],np.nan)
```

However, it raise an error:

```
emails_visits["date_after"]=np.where(emails_visits["type"]=="visit",emails_visits["Date"],np.nan)
      File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in where
    TypeError: The DType <class 'numpy.dtype[datetime64]'> could not be promoted by <class 'numpy.dtype[float64]'>. This means that no common DType exists for the given inputs. For example they cannot be stored in a single array unless the dtype is `object`. The full list of DTypes is: (<class 'numpy.dtype[datetime64]'>, <class 'numpy.dtype[float64]'>)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you using pandas?

Comment: yes, I use pandas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this if you want.

```
email_visits['date after'] = email_visits.apply(lambda x: x[2] if x[3] == 'visit' else '', axis=1)
```

Comment: thank you it helped, could you please explain why I need to add axis=1?

Comment: from the official documentation of apply  [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)  : "Objects passed to the function are Series objects whose index is either the DataFrame’s index (axis=0) or the DataFrame’s columns (axis=1)"  ...and since we need to compare different columns (row by row) axis=1 here

Answer (score 0):

The type `datetime64` of the column `Date` of `emails_visits` is incompatible with the one of `np.nan` which is a `np.float64`. Since it seems you use Pandas, you need to *use `pd.NA` instead* which is used for missing values (while `np.nan` means that the value is not a number and only applies for floating-point numbers). In fact, it is **better not to use `np.where` here but pandas functions**. Here is a simple solution:

```py
emails_visits["date_after"] = emails_visits["Date"].where(emails_visits["type"]=="visit")
```